# How to deal with many NAs in dataset when comparing several models?

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, model-selection

My task is to compare different logistic regression models to examine which theory better explains the data we have collected. In doing so, I have a set of IVs with a considerable amount of missing data (NAs). My issue is that when building a model with all IVs and in that process omitting the observations for which at least one of the IVs is missing, some of the effects that show up in models that consider only a subset of the IVs vanish. Even more, I stumble on perfect separation. At the same time, I understand that to compare models, I must test them all with the same data (thus, with all non-complete cases omitted).

So, my question is if there is a better way of dealing with these NAs, while still being able to compare the multiple models.

Comment: What are the reasons for the missing data?  This will indicate the extent to which values might be imputed to them, for instance.  And what is the purpose of the regression? If it is for prediction, then it might do you little good to include any explanatory variables (IVs) that potentially would have missing values.

Comment: Hi whuber. The purpose of the regression is to investigate significant factors in explaining a DV. And to compare whether models that incorporate new IVs (and thus support other theories) do explain better the DV. The domain is transport mode choice modeling, and IVs are related to life events or housing characteristics. We have a lot of missing data because people did not fill many of our questionnaires fully.